# Batch : Echo can not save to text file

Tags: batch-file

I want to save to text file, result of batch script bellow:

**My Run.bat contains :**

```
for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('findstr /L "Total " max_page.csv') do echo %%a> max_page.txt
set /p max_page=<max_page.txt
for /l %%i IN (1,1,%max_page%) do (
echo OPTIONS (SKIP=0, errors=1000) LOAD DATA  APPEND INTO TABLE tb_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'09' TRAILING NULLCOLS (no "TRIM (:no)",date_pymn DATE "DD-MM-YYYY") > data.ctl
)
```

Where my **max_page.csv** contains :

```
aaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccc

Total 6434 Record : 65 Page
```

Result of line `for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('findstr /L "Total " max_page.csv') do echo %%a> max_page.txt` is **`65`** and saved to txt file `(max_page.txt)`.

If I execute the `RUN.bat`, display on the screen error `LOAD was unexpected at this time`.
LOAD is part of line `echo OPTIONS (SKIP=0, errors=1000) LOAD DATA  APPEND INTO TABLE tb_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'09' TRAILING NULLCOLS (no "TRIM (:no)",date_pymn DATE "DD-MM-YYYY") > data.ctl`

Where mistake my script? Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to *escape* the **<kbd>)</kbd>** characters that are erroneously being interpreted as end-of-statement with a caret **<kbd>^</kbd>**

Hence (2 carets inserted)

```
echo OPTIONS (SKIP=0, errors=1000^) LOAD DATA  APPEND INTO TABLE tb_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'09' TRAILING NULLCOLS (no "TRIM (:no)",date_pymn DATE "DD-MM-YYYY"^) > data.ctl
```

There appears to be no logical reason for your second `for` loop - it merely writes the line of text to the file and then overwrites that file with the same line 64 more times (given `max_page` gets set to 65.)

Similarly, 'max_page.txt` is created and overwritten until the last "Total" line in the source file. It would be easier to use

```
for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('findstr /L "Total " max_page.csv') do set max_page%%a
```

and not create max_page.txt at all...

Comment: thank you very much. the `^` Work fine and I have fix my script as your advice.

Answer (score 1):

The first ) in

```
echo OPTIONS (SKIP=0, errors=1000) LOAD DATA  APPEND INTO TABLE tb_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'09' TRAILING NULLCOLS (no "TRIM (:no)",date_pymn DATE "DD-MM-YYYY") > data.ctl
```

is being interpreted as the end of the FOR loop. Since you only have one line in the loop, get rid of the opening and closing parens and put the entire FOR construct on one line like this

```
for /l %%i IN (1,1,%max_page%) do echo OPTIONS (SKIP=0, errors=1000) LOAD DATA  APPEND INTO TABLE tb_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'09' TRAILING NULLCOLS (no "TRIM (:no)",date_pymn DATE "DD-MM-YYYY") > data.ctl
```